# How to add text to a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to do some kind of GridView using [this official example](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) and I don't know how to add some text below the images. I tried this code for the adapter, but it is not working:

```
public class ImageAdapterForGridView extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapterForGridView(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            textView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            //textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        textView.setText(mThumbTexts[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

  /*  public TextView getTextView(int position, TextView convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        TextView textView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            textView = new TextView(mContext);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            textView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        } else {
            textView = convertView;
        }
        textView.setText(mThumbTexts[position]);
        return textView;
    }*/

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_facebook, R.drawable.ic_flickr,
            R.drawable.ic_gmail, R.drawable.ic_linkedin,
            R.drawable.ic_picasa, R.drawable.ic_myspace,
            R.drawable.ic_rss, R.drawable.ic_skype,
            R.drawable.ic_tuenti, R.drawable.ic_twitter,
            R.drawable.ic_windowslive, R.drawable.ic_vimeo,
            R.drawable.ic_yahoo, R.drawable.otro_32,
    };

    private String[] mThumbTexts = {
            "Facebook", "Flickr", "Gmail", "LinkedIn", "Picasa", "Myspace", "RSS", "Skype", "Tuenti",
            "Twitter", "WindowsLive", "Vimeo", "Yahoo", "Otros"
    };
}
```

Do you know how could I add some TextView the same way I do add the imageView??

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: You have goofed up big time here, we don't return a specific view in get view method, we return a Layout which is inflated as a View, and in that layout ImageView and a TextView are added

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm programming in Android for 1 week.

Comment: Basics are very important dude, first you should clear your basics and then proceed to development, maybe follow some famous tutorials or something

Comment: I do know basics are important, but it is not so clear for me, there are many many things.

Comment: yeah that's true, android is quite vast, but keep learning and you will master it in no time ;)

Answer (score 1):

in your `getView` method you are returning your `imageView` try adding yout `ImageView` and `TextView` to a `LinearLayout` and return that layout.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
...
layout.addView(imageView);
layout.addView(textView);
...
return layout;
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked for me that way :) Even tho I don't really know when getView is called, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an image with a label, you can go for a compound drawable. In Android a textview can have an image associated with it. You can achieve this through the [drawableTop/Left/Right/Bottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop) in XML, or through [setCompoundDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) programmatically. Check my answer to this question on more details in how you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26959558/1003528 with a pratical example for a gridview.